# Efficient way to find the sum of digits of an 8 digit number

Tags: c

I have to find the sum of the first 4 digits, the sum of the last 4 digits and compare them (of all the numbers betweem m and n). But when I submit my solution online there's a problem with the time limit.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int M, N, res = 0, cnt, first4, second4, sum1, sum2;

    scanf("%d", &M);
    scanf("%d", &N);

    for(cnt = M; cnt <= N; cnt++)
    {
        first4 = cnt % 10000;
        sum1 = first4 % 10 + (first4 / 10) % 10 + (first4 / 100) % 10 + (first4 / 1000) % 10;
        second4 = cnt / 10000;
        sum2 = second4 % 10 + (second4 / 10) % 10 + (second4 / 100) % 10 + (second4 / 1000) % 10;

        if(sum1 == sum2)
            res++;

    }

    printf("%d", res);


    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to find a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: Are you sure its the summing of digits that's slow? What is the range of `M` and `N`?

Comment: @rohit89 The range of M and N is 10000000 ≤ M < N ≤ 99999999

Comment: sum2 is going to change a lot slower than sum1. You could probably cache that or hoist it to an outer loop.

Comment: You know the numbers advance 1 by 1, so you can change sum2 after the 10,000 number changed, that will eliminate half the calculations. And you don't need to calculate sum1 but the first time, and then it will be just augmenting 1 by 1, it will make it 1000 more efficient if you do it that way

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review/optimization of a working code. It is better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Arlind I just realized, shouldn't you end the output with a newline? I suppose you feed it to some automatic tester, which may not get your output unless you finish the line. In case this is not the issue, have a look at the solution I proposed (it runs around ten thousand times faster).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, if you are still interested, there is a much faster way to do this.
Your task doesn't specifically require you to calculate the sums for all the numbers,
it only asks for the number of some *special* numbers.
In such cases optimization techniques like memoization or dynamic programming come really handy.

In this case, when you have the first four digits of some number (let them be 1234),
you calculate their sum (in this case 10) and you immediately know,
what is the sum of the other four digits supposed to be.

Any 4-digit number, that yields sum 10 can now be the other half to create a valid number.
Therefore total number of valid numbers beginning with 1234 is exactly the number of all four digit numbers that give the sum 10.

Now consider another number, say 3412. This number has also sum equal to 10,
therefore any right-side that completes 1234 also completes 3412.

What this means is that the number of valid numbers beginning with 3412 is the same
as the number of valid numbers beginning with 1234, which is in turn the *same as the total number of valid numbers, where the first half yields the sum 10*.

Therefore if we precompute for each `i` the number of four digit numbers
that yield the sum `i`, we would know for each first four digits the exact number of
combinations of last four digits that complete a valid number,
*without having to iterate over all 10000 of them*.

The following implementation of this algorithm

1. Precomputes number of different ending halves for each sum of the beginning half
2. Splits the [M,N] interval in three subintervals, because in the first and the last beginning not every ending is possible

This algorithm runs quadratically faster than the naive implementation (for sufficiently big `N-M`).

```
#include <string.h>

int sum_digits(int number) {
    return number%10 + (number/10)%10 + (number/100)%10 + (number/1000)%10;
}

int count(int M, int N) {
    if (M > N) return 0;

    int ret = 0;
    int tmp = 0;

    // for each i from 0 to 36 precompute number of ways we can get this sum
    // out of a four-digit number
    int A[37];
    memset(A, 0, 37*4);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9999; ++i) {
        ++A[sum_digits(i)];
    }

    // nearest multiple of 10000 greater than M
    int near_M = ((M+9999)/10000)*10000;

    // nearest multiple of 10000 less than N
    int near_N = (N/10000)*10000;

    // count all numbers up to first multiple of 10000
    tmp = sum_digits(M/10000);
    if (near_M <= N) {
        for (int i = M; i < near_M; ++i) {
            if (tmp == sum_digits(i % 10000)) {
                ++ret;
            }
        }
    }

    // count all numbers between the 10000 multiples, use the precomputed values
    for (int i = near_M / 10000; i < near_N / 10000; ++i) {
        ret += A[sum_digits(i)];
    }

    // count all numbers after the last multiple of 10000
    tmp = sum_digits(N / 10000);
    if (near_N >= M) {
        for (int i = near_N; i <= N; ++i) {
            if (tmp == sum_digits(i % 10000)) {
                ++ret;
            }
        }
    }

    // special case when there are no multiples of 10000 between M and N
    if (near_M > near_N) {
        for (int i = M; i <= N; ++i) {
            if (sum_digits(i / 10000) == sum_digits(i % 10000)) {
                ++ret;
            }
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

EDIT: I fixed the bugs mentioned in the comments.

Comment: This is one of those "work smarter, not harder" things I was talking about. Your realization that permutations of digits give the same answer allows you to speed up the calculation by (4*3*2)^2 when groups of 4 digits are different, slightly less when they are the same. Didn't check whether you get the same answer as the "slow" method. Do you?

Comment: This is indeed fast, but there's a bug lurking in here somewhere. `count(10000000,10000001)` returns 0 when it should return 1.

Comment: @Floris I checked for most of the special cases, except the one @Michael pointed out :) now I see it needs a few fixes, among others fix this condition `if (near_N >= M)` and add special case `if (near_M > near_N)`. For now it works for sufficiently distant `M` and `N`.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if this would be significantly faster or not, but you might try breaking the number into two 4 digit numbers, then use a table lookup to get the sums. That way there's only one division operation instead of eight.

You can pre-compute the table of 10000 sums so it gets compiled in so there's no runtime cost at all.

Another slightly more complicated, but probably much faster, approach that can be used is have a table or map of 10000 elements that's the reverse of the sum lookup table where you can map the sum to the set of four digit numbers that would produce that sum.  That way, when you have to find the result for a particular range 10000 number range, it's a simple lookup on the sum of the most significant four digits.  For example, to find the result for the range 12340000 - 12349999, you could use a binary search on the reverse lookup table to quickly find how many numbers in the range 0 - 9999 have the sum 10 (1 + 2 + 3 + 4).

Again - this reverse sum lookup table can be pre-computed and compiled in as a static array.

In this way, the results for complete 10000 number ranges are performed with a couple binary searches.  Any partial ranges can also be handled with the reverse lookup table with slightly more complication due to having to ignore matches that are from out of the range of interest.  But that complication only has to happen at most twice for your whole set of subranges.

This would reduce the complexity of the algorithm from O(N*N) to O(N log N) (I think).

---

update:

Here's some timings I got (Win32-x86, using VS 2013 (MSVC 12) with release build default options):

```
       range    range     
       start    end        count    time
================================================

alg1(10000000, 99999999): 4379055, 1.854 seconds
alg2(10000000, 99999999): 4379055, 0.049 seconds
alg3(10000000, 99999999): 4379055, 0.001 seconds
```

with:

- `alg1()` is the original code from the question
- `alg2()` is my first cut suggestion (lookup precomputed sums)
- `alg3()` is the second suggestion (binary search lookup of sum matches using a table sorted by sums)

I'm actually surprised at the difference between `alg1()` to `alg2()`

Comment: Very interesting. Good Job.

Comment: Can you test mine? I am curious to see how it will fit

Comment: The test code can be found here: https://gist.github.com/mburr/7881662 in case anyone is interested. Of general interest in there might be the small C `bsearch_lbound()` and `bsearch_ubound()` functions to locate the lower and upper bounds - they can be a nice alternative to the `bsearch()` function when you have arrays with non-unique keys.

Comment: I tested on my vm multiple times:
alg1(10000000, 99999999): 4379055, 4.990 seconds
alg2(10000000, 99999999): 4379055, 0.340 seconds
alg3(10000000, 99999999): 4379055, 2.010 seconds
It is strange that the difference on my vm is so high for alg3. There must be something not optimized there.

Comment: @Jekyll: `alg3()` calls the `bsearch_lbound()` and `bsearch_ubound()` functions which have a performance killing `assert()` that verifies the array is sorted. Either comment out those `assert()` calls or make sure `NDEBUG` is defined when you build your test.

Comment: No difference :O, with or without assert similar results... `alg1(10000000, 99999999): 4379055, 5.120 seconds`
 `alg2(10000000, 99999999): 4379055, 0.350 seconds`
 `alg3(10000000, 99999999): 4379055, 2.020 seconds`
my algorithm 0.96. So actually algorithm2 is the best with my VM

Comment: @Jekyll: I'm not sure I can account for the `alg3()` performance you're seeing.  I've updated the gist a couple times, so you might want to try downloading it again. But there's no change in there that I'm aware of that should significantly affect `alg3()` performance other than I removed the `assert()` calls.  I've run the tests on both Windows and Linux, using both MSVC (v12) and gcc (4.6.3 and 4.7.2) with similar results all around.

Comment: I have also added an `alg4()` to the gist that uses @pepo's idea of a pre-built table of counts of four-digit sums. However, that algorithm still needs to use some other algorithm for the partial ranges that one might need to deal with when the range starts or ends on a non-10000 number block boundary. In this case I use `alg3()` to handle the partial ranges.  In any case, the `alg3()` and `alg4()` runs are at the limit of `clock()`'s resolution.  I'm sure that `alg4()` is faster, but don't know by how much

Comment: Ok I changed Linux VM on a pc which has better performances:
My algorithms without tables: `opt1 4379055 0.620000` `opt2 4379055 0.420000`. The four algorithm reported by you (plus original): `alg1(10000000, 99999999):     4379055, 2.460000 seconds
alg2(10000000, 99999999):     4379055, 0.210000 seconds
alg3(10000000, 99999999):     4379055, 0.010000 seconds
alg4(10000000, 99999999):     4379055, 0.000000 seconds
alg5(10000000, 99999999):     4379055, 0.000000 seconds` so here it is working as expected. It must be something related to the specific VM memory performances.

Answer (score 3):

You are going about this the wrong way. A little bit of cleverness is worth a lot of horsepower. You should not be comparing the first and last four digits of every number.

First - notice that the first four digits will change very slowly - so for sure you can have a loop of 10000 of the last four digits without re-computing the first sum.

Second - the sum of digits repeats itself every 9th number (until you get overflow). This is the basis of the "number is divisible by 9 if sum of digits is divisible by 9". example:

```
1234  - sum = 10
1234 + 9 = 1243   - sum is still 10
```

What this means is that the following will work pretty well (pseudo code):

```
take first 4 digits of M, find sum (call it A)
find sum of last four digits of M (call it B)
subtract: C = (A - B)
If C < 9:
  D = C%9
  first valid number is [A][B+D]. Then step by 9, until...
```

You need to think a bit about the "until", and also about what to do when C >= 9. This means you need to find a zero in B and replace it with a 9, then repeat the above.

If you want to do nothing else, then see that you don't need to re-compute the sum of digits that did not change. In general when you add 1 to a number, the sum of digits increases by 1 (unless there is carry - then it decreases by 9; and that happens every 9th, 99th (twice -> sum drops by 18), 999th (drop by 27), etc.

I hope this helps you think about the problem differently.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to try an approach which doesn't make use of the lookup table (even though I know that the second one should be faster) to investigate how much we can speedup just optimizing calculus. This algorithm can be used where stack is an important resource...
Let's work on the idea that divisions and modulus are slow, for example in [cortex R4](http://www.arm.com/files/pdf/Cortex-R4-white-paper.pdf) a 32 bit division requires up to 16 loops while a multiplication can be done in a single loop, with older ARMs things can be even worse.
This basic idea will try to get rid of them using digit arrays instead of integers. To keep it simple let's show an implementation using printf before a `pseudo optimized` version.

```
 void main() {
   int count=0;
   int nmax;       
   char num[9]={0};
   int n;
   printf( "Insert number1 ");
   scanf( "%d", &nm );
   printf( "Insert number2 ");
   scanf( "%d", &nmax );
   while( nm <= nmax ) {
       int sumup=0, sumdown=0;
       sprintf( num, "%d", nm );
       for( n=0; n<4; n++ ) {
         sumup += num[n] -'0'; // subtracting '0' is not necessary (see below)
         sumdown += num[7-n]-'0';  // subtracting '0' is not necessary (see below)
       }
       if( sumup == sumdown ) {
       /* whatever */
          count++;
       }
       nm++;
   }
 }
```

You may want to check that the string is a valid number using `strtol` before calling the for loop and the length of the string using `strlen`. I set here fixed values as you required (I assume length always 8).

The downside of the shown algorithm is the `sprintf` for any loop that may do thing worse... So we apply two major changes

1. we use [0-9] instead of ['0';'9']
2. we drop the sprintf for a faster solution which takes in account that we need to format a digit string starting from the previous number (n-1)

Finally the **pseudo optimized** algorithm should look something like the one shown below in which all divisions and modules are removed (apart from the first number) and bytes are used instead of ASCII.

```
void pseudo_optimized() {
   int count=0;
   int nmax,nm;       
   char num[9]={0};
   int sumup=0, sumdown=0;
   int n,i;
   printf( "Insert number1 ");
   scanf( "%d", &nm );
   printf( "Insert number2 ");
   scanf( "%d", &nmax );
   n = nm;
   for( i=7; i>=0; i-- ) {
      num[i]=n%10;
      n/=10;
   }
   while( nm <= nmax ) {

       sumup = num[0] + num[1] + num[2] + num[3];
       sumdown = num[7] + num[6] + num[5] + num[4];
       if( sumup == sumdown ) {
       /* whatever */
          count++;
       }
       nm++;
       /* Following loop is a faster sprintf replacement and
        * it will exit at the first value 9 times on 10
        */
        for( i=7; i>=0; i-- ) {
         if( num[i] == 9 ) {
            num[i]=0;
         } else {
            num[i] += 1;
            break;
         }
       }
   }
}
```

Original algo on my vm ***5.500000 s***, this algo ***0.950000 s*** tested for [00000000=>99999999]
The weak point of this algorithm is that it uses sum of digits (which are not necessary and a for...loop that can be unrolled.

*** update ***
further optimization. The sums of digits are not necessary.... thinking about it I could improve the algorithm in the following way:

```
int optimized() {
   int nmax=99999999,
   int nm=0;
   clock_t time1, time2;
   char num[9]={0};
   int sumup=0, sumdown=0;
   int n,i;
   int count=0;
   n = nm;
   time1 = clock();
   for( i=7; i>=0; i-- ) {
      num[i]=n%10;
      n/=10;
   }
   sumup = num[0] + num[1] + num[2] + num[3];
   sumdown = num[7] + num[6] + num[5] + num[4];
   while( nm <= nmax ) {
      if( sumup == sumdown ) {
         count++;
      }
      nm++;
      for( i=7; i>=0; i-- ) {
         if( num[i] == 9 ) {
            num[i]=0;
            if( i>3 )
               sumdown-=9;
            else
               sumup-=9;
     } else {
            num[i] += 1;
            if( i>3 )
              sumdown++;
            else
              sumup++;
            break;
         }
      }
   }
   time2 = clock();
   printf( "Final-now %d %f\n", count, ((float)time2 - (float)time1) / 1000000);
   return 0;
}
```

with this we arrive to ***0.760000 s*** which is 3 times slower than the result achieved on the same machine using lookup tables.

*** update*** Optimized and unrolled:

```
int optimized_unrolled(int nm, int nmax) {
   char num[9]={0};
   int sumup=0, sumdown=0;
   int n,i;
   int count=0;
   n = nm;
   for( i=7; i>=0; i-- ) {
      num[i]=n%10;
      n/=10;
   }
   sumup = num[0] + num[1] + num[2] + num[3];
   sumdown = num[7] + num[6] + num[5] + num[4];
   while( nm <= nmax ) {
      if( sumup == sumdown ) {
         count++;
   }
   nm++;
   if( num[7] == 9 ) {
      num[7]=0;
      if( num[6] == 9 ) {
         num[6]=0;
         if( num[5] == 9 ) {
            num[5]=0;
            if( num[4] == 9 ) {
               num[4]=0;
               sumdown=0;
               if( num[3] == 9 ) {
                  num[3]=0;
                  if( num[2] == 9 ) {
                     num[2]=0;
                     if( num[1] == 9 ) {
                        num[1]=0;
                        num[0]++;
                        sumup-=26;
                     } else {
                        num[1]++;
                        sumup-=17;
                     }
                  } else {
                     num[2]++;
                     sumup-=8;
                  }
               } else {
                  num[3]++;
                  sumup++;
               }
            } else {
               num[4]++;
               sumdown-=26;
            }
        } else {
           num[5]++;
           sumdown-=17;
        }
     } else {
        num[6]++;
        sumdown-=8;
     }
  } else {
     num[7]++;
     sumdown++;
  }
}
return count;
}
```

Unrolling vectors improves the speed of about 50%. The algorithm costs now ***0.36000 s***,  by the way it makes use of the stack a bit more than the previous solution (as some 'if' statements may result in a push, so it cannot be always used). The result is comparable with Alg2@Michael Burr on the same machine, [Alg3-Alg5]@Michael Burr are a lot faster where stack isn't a concern.

***Note*** all test where performed on a intel VMS. I will try to run all those algos on a ARM device if I will have time.

Comment: The user will input two number M and N. Then the program must find the count of all the numbers from M to N which have the sum of the first 4 digits equal to the sum of the last 4 digits. So, the length of the number is always 8. How could a convert each of the numbers in a string? I don't think it would be faster if I use a nested loop.

Comment: @Arlind It will be faster as you get already a string that you need to convert using %d in your scanf while you can collect it directly using a string. moreover you don't use divisions and modules which are lot slower than subtractions. so it worth trying. and if not fast enough you can unroll the loop

Comment: @Arlind Sorry I misunderstood your comment... I am going to adapt that here

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int M, N;

    scanf("%d", &M);
    scanf("%d", &N);

    static int table[10000] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    {
        register int i=0,i1,i2,i3,i4;
        for(i1=0;i1<10;++i1)
        for(i2=0;i2<10;++i2)
        for(i3=0;i3<10;++i3)
        for(i4=0;i4<10;++i4)
            table[i++]=table[i1]+table[i2]+table[i3]+table[i4];
    }
    register int cnt = M, second4 = M % 10000;
    int res = 0, first4 = M / 10000, sum1=table[first4];
    for(; cnt <= N; ++cnt){
        if(sum1 == table[second4])
            ++res;
        if(++second4>9999){
            second4 -=10000;
            if(++first4>9999)break;
            sum1 = table[first4];
        }
    }
    printf("%d", res);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @EricPostpischil i fixed it. It was found barely what you say. I am a fool.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I appreciate the your kindness and  patience.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the numbers are fixed like that, then you can you substring functions to get the components and compare them. Otherwise, your modulator operations are contributing unnecessary time.

Comment: Could you please explain this some more?

Answer (score 0):

i found faster algorithm:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    clock_t time1, time2;
    int M, N, res = 0, cnt, first4, second4, sum1, sum2,last4_ofM,first4_ofM,last4_ofN,first4_ofN,j;

    scanf("%d", &M);
    scanf("%d", &N);

    time1 = clock();


    for(cnt = M; cnt <= N; cnt++)
    {
        first4 = cnt % 10000;
        sum1 = first4 % 10 + (first4 / 10) % 10 + (first4 / 100) % 10 + (first4 / 1000) % 10;
        second4 = cnt / 10000;
        sum2 = second4 % 10 + (second4 / 10) % 10 + (second4 / 100) % 10 + (second4 / 1000) % 10;

        if(sum1 == sum2)
            res++;

    }
    time2 = clock();
    printf("%d\n", res);
    printf("first algorithm time: %f\n",((float)time2 - (float)time1) / 1000000.0F );
    res=0;

    time1 = clock();
    first4_ofM = M / 10000;
    last4_ofM = M % 10000;
    first4_ofN = N / 10000;
    last4_ofN = N % 10000;

    for(int i = first4_ofM; i <= first4_ofN; i++)
    {
        sum1 = i % 10 + (i / 10) % 10 + (i / 100) % 10 + (i / 1000) % 10;

        if ( i == first4_ofM ) 
            j = last4_ofM;
        else 
            j = 0;
        while ( j <= 9999)
        {
            sum2 = j % 10 + (j / 10) % 10 + (j / 100) % 10 + (j / 1000) % 10;
            if(sum1 == sum2)
                res++;
            if ( i == first4_ofN && j == last4_ofN ) break;
            j++;
        }

    }
    time2 = clock();
        printf("%d\n", res);
        printf("second algorithm time: %f\n",((float)time2 - (float)time1) / 1000000.0F );
    return 0;
}
```

i just dont need to count sum of the first four digits all the time the number in changed. I need to count it one time per 10000 iterations. In worst case output is:

```
10000000
99999999
4379055
first algorithm time: 5.160000
4379055
second algorithm time: 2.240000
```

about half the better result.